# Process will not trigger on second date

Tags: formula, formula-field, process-builder, date, time-dependent-workflow

I have set up a process on builder that should trigger when "a record is created or edited" and given the following criteria :

```
(OR(TODAY() = DATEVALUE('2016-12-8'), TODAY() = DATEVALUE('2016-12-7')))
&& 
([BD_Employee__c].Annual_Leave_Balance__c > 10)
&& 
([BD_Employee__c].Number_of_years_with_iDE__c < 3)
&& 
(ISPICKVAL([BD_Employee__c].Staff_Type__c, "National"))
```

The action is to create a record. I did a test scenario, where I created a record on the first date (7th), and the resulting action record gets created. However, I need it to also evaluate on the 8th, but the next day, it doesn't evaluate and the record does not get created.

Why does the process evaluate on the first date, but not the second?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that Process Builder (or workflow) only executes the triggering conditions when a DML event occurs (insert or update).

The day flopping over to tomorrow is not a DML event on the object.

There are a couple of workarounds

- Use scheduled apex to check every day
- Use time-based process builder actions that upon execution, set the conditions in the target object so the time-based process executes on the subsequent day. [Here's an example](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=906300000010wzuAAA) to give you insight